# Unable to remove prefix character from the richtextbox

Tags: c#, events, barcode-scanner

Am trying to show a specific string the scanned output of barcode scanner. I have configured my barcode scanner to put a $ at the end of every scanned barcode. After that am trying to display the filtered output in the rich textbox. Am using the keypress event for this purpose. This is what happens now. My scanner reads barcode starts typing and at the end when the scanner presses $ sign the keypress event for the asci of $ is being triggered and I filter my scanner output there to show the final result in the richtextbox. However when I debug the prefixed $ sign is not being shown in the same event function when I get the text from the textbox in a variable string.
Here is my code: Please see the comments. I have updated my code to show debugged output with code lines

```
private void CheckEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)36)
    {
        String newstring;

        var str = richTextBox1.Text;   
        int numlines = str.Split('\n').Length;
        var strArr = str.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
        if (numlines > 2)
        {
            if (strArr[2].Length == 6)
            {
                var final = strArr[1];
                newstring = final.Remove(final.Length - 2, 2);
                richTextBox1.Text = newstring;
                String test = richTextBox1.Text; ////shows 3740588609843 not $3740588609843
                int len = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
               // test = test.Remove(test.Length - 14, 1); //removes 3 rather than $
                richTextBox1.Text = test; //result displayed is $740588609843
                cnic = newstring;
            }
            if (strArr[3].Length == 6)
            {
                var final = strArr[2];
                richTextBox1.Text = final;
                cnic = final;
            }
        }
        if (numlines < 3)
        {
            if (strArr[0].Length == 25)
            {
                var final = strArr[0];
                newstring = final.Remove(0, 12);
                richTextBox1.Text = newstring;
                cnic = newstring;
            }
        }
        if (cnic == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please scan the id card through scanner again!");
        }

    }
}
```

Why is it happening so??? how can I correct this ?? I want to remove $ sign but code is not detecting it though it exists on the start in the richtextbox

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
richTextBox1.Text = test.TrimStart('$'); //result displayed is $740588609843
```

Comment: the point is it is not picking up $ sign. tried. Isnt working!

Comment: not showing $ sign in richtextbox.text in debugging but showing it in program

Comment: @user3345361: are you checking for $ sign using this statement ->  if `if(e.KeyChar == (char)36)`?

Comment: even when I get richtextbox.Text after getting out of the above condition the result is with $ sign in the gui but not in the debugging mode!

Comment: you are taking input from RichTextBox(with $) and trying to remove $ and appending/displaying the same text(without $) on Richtextbox right?